# MediaElement.js stops other players if another starts

Tags: html, media-player, media, mediaelement.js

I am using MediaElement.js and need other players to stop playing if another is starts.

This question has been asked before but I am a little confused as to how to apply this code.

I have seen others had solved this and had it working by using the following in jQuery:

```
$('video,audio').each(function() {
  $(this)[0].pause();
});
```

Where should I put this code? Or where exactly in the jquery.js file should I put it? I can't get it to work.

I need my other players to stop playing if another starts.

Answer (score 1):

```js
/*new MediaElementPlayer('.player_1', {success: function(media, node, player) {
    // this will be undefined since it's the player with buttons
alert(player.paused);
    // this will be a real value since it's the underlying mediaelement
alert(media.paused);
}
});*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('audio').mediaelementplayer({
        alwaysShowControls: true,
        features: ['playpause','volume','progress'],
        audioVolume: 'horizontal'
        //audioWidth: 400,
        //audioHeight: 120
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mediaelementjs.com/js/mejs-2.8.2/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://mediaelementjs.com/js/mejs-2.8.2/mediaelementplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<audio src="http://mediaelementjs.com/media/AirReview-Landmarks-02-ChasingCorporate.mp3" class="player_1"></audio>
<audio src="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3" class="player_2"></audio>
```